# Erro NaN ao usar ordenação datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-datatables

Estou tentando criar uma ordenação de datas em um `dataTable` onde o formato será `dd-MM-aaaa hh:MM:ss`.

o código abaixo até funciona o problema que ele da algum erro de conversão sempre no primeiro valor que fica como `NaN` e quando é feito a ordenação fica fixo.

código:

```
jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort['uk_date-pre'] = function (a) {
    a = a.replace("-", "/").replace("-","/");
   // a = a.slice(0, -2) + '' + a.slice(-2);
    var date = Date.parse(a);
    return typeof date === 'number' ? date : -1;
}
jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort['uk_date-asc'] = function (a, b) {
    return ((a < b) ? -1 : ((a > b) ? 1 : 0));
}
jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort['uk_date-desc'] = function (a, b) {
    return ((a < b) ? 1 : ((a > b) ? -1 : 0));
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Não estou conseguindo localizar a falha, sendo os demais dados tem esse formato.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente:

```
jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort['uk_date-pre'] = function (a) {
    var partsDate = a.split("/");
    var date = new Date(parseInt(partsDate[2], 10),
                  parseInt(partsDate[1], 10) - 1,
                  parseInt(partsDate[0], 10));


    return = typeof date === 'number' ? date : -1;
}
```

**Exemplo**

```js
var strDate = "21/09/2018 09:16:35"

var partsDate = strDate.split("/");
var date = new Date(parseInt(partsDate[2], 10),
  parseInt(partsDate[1], 10) - 1,
  parseInt(partsDate[0], 10));


console.log("Resultado: ", typeof date === 'number' ? date : -1);
```